# Ngrep on OSX not working?

Tags: macos, ngrep

How do I even install ngrep on mac os x?
I tried with brew, no avail...
It gives me errors when I use ngrep
but when I use sngrep it gives me more errors ): (it seems like progress though)

```
Unable to handle linktype 149
With command
sudo sngrep -d any '.flv' port 80
With ngrep error:
interface: any
exit
0 received, 0 dropped
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not *exactly* an answer but recently I wanted to use ngrep also, had some issues then `brew install`'d wireshark. After it installed I got a message like this:

> If your list of available capture interfaces is empty (default OS X
>   behavior), try installing ChmodBPF from homebrew cask:
>
> brew cask install wireshark-chmodbpf
>
> This creates an 'access_bpf' group and adds a launch daemon that
>   changes the permissions of your BPF devices so that all users in that
>   group have both read and write access to those devices.

I wonder if this "chmodbpf" thing would be helpful to you, perhaps there is an ngrep version of it?

Btw I'm on OSX Yosemite (whatever's latest I think it's named Yosemite).

Comment: I am also running OSX Yosemite. I will look into it! Thank you!

Comment: in the end wireshark gave me trouble so i said eff it and went with tcpdump. some help on that over here https://danielmiessler.com/study/tcpdump/.

Comment: I see! I will try tcpdump.